# C# Looking for a flexible data structure

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am mulling over a small issue and would appreciate peoples opinions.
I'm making a C# plugin for Unity for a C++ particle simulation library. I'd like a way to represent all the particles in the system so the end user can access the data easily. At the moment each particle is represented by a struct like so..

```
public struct Particle
{
    public Vector3 Position;
    public Color _Color;
    public float Age;
    public float Weight;
    public Vector3 Velocity;
    public int UserData
}
```

The issue I have with this however is that in most cases you will not not bother retrieving all of the info available in the struct from the simulation. For instance you might only want to retrieve the position and colour info each frame to improve performance. In that case my struct will have lots of uninitialised fields + will be taking up more memory than it needs (there will be 1000's of them btw)
I cant use a class hieratchy as any combination of fields might be used in different situations.
One approach I did think of is this..

```
public struct Particle
{
    public Dictionary<string,object> Data;
}
```

Creating them looks something like this..

```
Particle parttest = new Particle{Data = new Dictionary<string,object>()};
parttest.Data.Add("Position",(object)Vector3.one);
parttest.Data.Add("Weight",(object)1.8745f);
```

and cast back to the appropriate class when reading them.
So I can have a particle with just, say, color, weight and position data contained in it and nothing else.
What do ye think?

Comment: At least make it of type class.

Comment: Use classes, sub classes, interfaces etc to split your "structure" into smaller segments

Comment: Are you actually running out of memory, or just prematurely optimizing?  I'd say boxing would be an issue with your second approach.

Comment: yeah I'm prematurely optimizing!

Comment: Dictionaries also have a significant overhead when they only store a few items.  Particle systems tend to have a lot of particles, if yours does too then this could become a problem area for you pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can envision two approaches:

a) You say that you cannot use classes "as any combination of fields might be used". But maybe composition (as opposed to inheritance) would do the job: a particle could have a DisplayBehavior, a MovementBehavior, etc. And those behaviors would hold the actual properties. Would this fit your problem?

b) Otherwise, if the enumeration of all properties of a particle can be slow (a few microseconds) while the retrieval of the values of one or two specific properties must be fast, the proper solution is to have property stores: for each property you have one structure that holds the values of all particles. Basically you store the (particle-id, property-value) information, either in a flat array or a dictionary. This is the solution used by WPF for example and this is cache-efficient and memory-savvy.

Meanwhile you would store nothing in the Particle structure, to the point that you may consider removing this type and only store particle identifiers (possibly a ParticleID enum to make your code more explicit). Or you could keep this type and add properties that would manipulate the global property stores.

**PS:** one note about structs: do you understand them correctly? In most cases using a large struct is a bad idea because this involves many memory copies. The only case when this tax is not paid is when the struct can be accessed by its address, for example when you manipulate it through its index in an array (particles[index].Position = ...).

Comment: B sounds good thanks! I think A is a bit too elaborate if I am understanding it correctly (I will read up on behaviours)  Thanks for the PS btw. I think I am ok in that regard as they are stored in a big array as part of a class which takes care of them